# Regex for BBCode with optional parameters

Tags: regex

I'm currently stuck on a regex. I'm trying to fetch the contents of a BBCode, that has optional params and maybe different notations:

```
[tag]https://example.com/1[/tag]
[tag='https://example.com/2'][/tag]
[tag="http://another-example.com/whatever"][/tag]
[tag=ftp://an-ftp-host][/tag]
[tag='https://example.com/3',left][/tag]
[tag="https://example.com/4",right][/tag]
[tag=https://example.com/5][/tag]
[tag=https://example.com/i-need-this-one,right]http://example.com/i-dont-need-this-one[/tag]
```

The 2nd param can just be left or right and if this is given, i need the URL from the first param. Otherwise, i need that one between the tags.

An url as param can be wrapped within `'` or `"` or without any of these.

My current regular expression is this:

`~\[tag(?|=[\'"]?+([^]"\']++)[\'"]?+]([^[]++)|](([^[]++)))\[/tag]~i`

However, this one also includes the 2nd param in the match list and a lot more of things, that i don't want to match.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you highlight separately each instance and order you prefer to match? This is probably not as simple as you think.

Comment: Every 1st URL. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some changes to do what you want. I've included your version here for easy comparison:

Yours: http://regex101.com/r/dE4aE4/1

```
\[tag(?:=[\'"]?(.*)[\'"]?)?]([^]]*)?\[/tag]
```

Mine: http://regex101.com/r/dE4aE4/3

```
\[tag(?:=[\'"]?([^,]*?)(?:,[^]'"]+)?[\'"]?)?]([^\[]+)?\[/tag]
```

Observe that I've changed a bit to get the URL without the coma (,): from `(.*)` to `([^,]*?)(?:,[^]'"]+)?`

I've also fixed the content part: from `([^]]*)?` to `([^\[]+)?`

Comment: Seems to work. Any idea, what's causing these empty 2nd matches? And i just noticed, that the regex on the page is another one than the one which i've tried, first :P

Comment: Fixed. It was the * inside the content match. Changed it to a + and it's done.

Comment: Thank you :) Looks like the solution, that i was looking for. But one more thing: I can't figure out, why the first tag is matched in 2 and not in 1. Would this be possible?

Comment: @SoftCreatR - The first sample test string url is matched in group 2 because it is a stand alone tag `[tag]`. There is a problem with this regex though. You can't tell the difference without post-processing the match. If you have an engine that does conditionals, you can do this `\[tag(?:=[\'"]?([^,]*?)(?:,[^]'"]+)?[\'"]?)?](?(1)[^\[]*|([^\[]+))\[/tag]` and catenate `$1$2` for the answer. As with everything regex wise, nothing is a simple as it appears.